# phalcon : volt get value from array which key taken from variable

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

In phalcon templating engine volt (which is similar to twig) you can fetch all records by :

```
{% for product in products %}
    Name: {{ product.name }}
    Description: {{ product.description }}
    price: {{ product.price}}
{% endfor  %}
```

So, in my scenario, I'm building a crud template which will be used for different kind of models. What I wanted to achieve in this template is that every columns in this view are not hard-coded. So I store the columns I wanted to show into an array (defined in the controller, passed to the view) :

```
$cols = ['name','description','price']
```

In the view, to make it display all columns :

```
{% for product in products %}
   {% for col in cols %}
       {{ col }}: {{ product.col }}
   {% endfor  %}
{% endfor  %}
```

Obviously, this will result in error, because there is no "col" in product.

Is there any solution or alternative for this ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible (yet). But luckily you can extend Volt http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/1.2.6/reference/volt.html#extending-volt

Comment: I believe than this can help: [link](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/1.2.6/reference/volt.html#id3). I dont tested, so not posted a answer. Create a funcion and pass the parameters like: `{% funcName({{product}}, {{col}}) %}`

Comment: Thanks, I look up the documentation and still confused of where to start. I know I have to create a function, 1st argument accept an array, and 2nd argument as its key, return the value which the key match in the array. But, where should I put the code, do I have to make separate file for custom code, I don't really know. The documentation showing different example without any clarification of the details...

Comment: Look at this http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#id3. Basically you need to change your bootstrap file, where services are being registered (like here https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/public/index.php#L77)

Comment: Can't you use generalized field names for that? since you are using CRUD and your template looks the same, feels like you can use the same field names across the models.

Comment: Just curious, did you already checked the [**phalcon-devtools**](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools)? There's a CRUD application to kick start that kind of implementation or at least serve as reference on how to deal with models in a abstract way.

Comment: @Fratyr field names are differ from each model, cant do that.
I did start with devtools, now I'm going to replace all those separate views and controllers into a single crud controller & view set. 
I managed to register a custom function but stuck on the "value-passing". I don't really understand why there are $resolvedArgs &  $exprArgs. The array (1st arg) and key (2nd arg) which I passed on this function are not properly passed (read as the exact variable name instead of its values). I'm still tinkering with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While frustrated tinkering with volt extension, I found a simpler solution :

1. Convert the model object into array. In the controller : `$products->toArray()`
2. Simply, in the view, to display specific value of specific key from an array : `{{ product[key] }}`

Problem solved, though because it is now not in form of object, I can't access object property using dot like `{{ product.some_field }}`, instead `{{ product['some_field'] }}`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the readAttribute() function:
http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1231/volt-access-to-object-property-using-variable

```
{{ product.readAttribute(col) }}
```

Comment: Not working at all. Error message: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::readAttribute()`.

Comment: If the error says `stdClass`, that clearly means that you didn't give a model object, as in Phalcon all objects inherit from Phalcon\Mvc\Model constructor. And the initial question clearly implies it: `fetch all records`.

Comment: I have inherit the model class from  `Phalcon\Mvc\Model`. And I'm using Phalcon 2.0.

Comment: I really doubt that: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/2.0.0/phalcon/mvc/model.zep#L3145 => the method exists, and you have «stdClass» in your error description, which means that you're dumping a default class, not a Phalcon object. Try a `{{ dump(product) }}` in volt, you'll see that's not a Phalcon object.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Because I get the object using `{% set i18nCategoryName = courseCategory['courseCategoryName'] | json_decode %}`. And I want to get the attribute `{language}` (is a variable) of the `i18nCategoryName`. So this method doesn't work for me.

Comment: You may use `defined` in this case, perhaps it would work as expected: `{% if i18nCategoryName.property is defined %}` ... `{% endif %}`